# ImportError: cannot import name 'correct_pad' from 'keras_applications'

Tags: keras, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to import segmentation_models in google colab, but I got this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'correct_pad' from 'keras_applications' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_applications/**init**.py)

I use:
Python 3.7
segmentation-models = 0.2.1
keras = 2.2.2

Comment: did you find any solution? I got the same error in the same environment!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and installing version 1.0.8 saved me!
use the code below in your colab environment:

```
!pip install keras_applications==1.0.8
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did the same solution and it worked for me.